# Getting the latest version of Android SDK for Ubuntu using wget

Tags: android, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to create a `Dockerfile` for an `Ubuntu` image and in that I'm trying to install `Android SDK` using the following command

```
https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.3.4-linux.tgz \
```

However I know for sure 24.3.4 is not the latest version of SDK. How do I find out the latest version of `Android SDK`. I tried going here

`https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html`

But even that's does not give me anything about SDK.

Can you pls help?

Comment: Why not just use sdkmanager?

Answer (score -3):

I just extract the url of latest sdk for Linux by doing:

```
wget https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=")' index.html | grep "tools_r.*linux"
```

You could possibly export it as a variable in your dockerfile.